Kids/Teen show about a girl chosen by a male celebrity to record a song with him
I'm trying to remember this show, I remember seeing ads for it a few years ago. It is a kids' show, or a teen show, and was probably on Nick, Teen Nick, Disney, etc. It is about a girl who, if I remember correctly, was chosen by a famous male singer at a concert to record a song with him. I think the singer's name was something like Eric/Evan Duran (the character, not the actor), and he had relatively short dark hair. The show was largely about music, there are multiple scenes in a recording studio, but the only song I remember them recording was called 'Could've Been Mars', 'Mars', or something like that. I think the girl had brown hair, and the actress who played her had previously done some soap opera.
I think I also remember a scene at a hospital, where Eric Duran is trying to get into a certain hospital room, but the paparazzi are chasing him at the elevator. Someone then gets hit in the face in the hospital room, as a 'stay away from her' type thing.
I also distinctly remember some video recorded by the cast where the actor who plays Eric Duran jumps up in a hallway and turns horizontal, pushing his arms and legs out to hold himself up between two parallel walls. I think he may have done something similar in a scene at a hospital.
I think a few characters sing in the series, but the only ones I remember singing are Eric Duran and the girl.

Sounds like the Nick at Nite show Hollywood Heights. From IMDb:

Loren (Brittany Underwood) a smart, shy and independent high school senior who has ambitions of being a songwriter and secretly sends her song lyrics to her celebrity crush, rock superstar Eddie Duran (Cody Longo). Loren's wildest dreams come true when she not only wins a songwriting competition sponsored by Eddie, but strikes up a friendship with her idol. 

And here's her song, (Might As Well Be) Mars:



